# How is protobuf 3 singular different than optional

Tags: protocol-buffers

Looking at the proto3 reference:

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#simple

It says this about `singular`:

```
singular: a well-formed message can have zero or one of this field (but not more than one).
```

It's not clear to me how this is different than `optional`. Is `singular` just an explicit way of stating that something is `optional` (which is now implicit for proto3)? Or is there something else this does that I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Optional is `proto2` syntax. Singular is `proto3` syntax.

In proto3, `singular` is the default rule. As today the documentation needs to be improved, and there's an open issue: [google/protobuf#3457](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/3457).

See also [google/protobuf#2497 why messge type remove 'required,optional'?](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/2497), and also haberman's comment on [GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python#1402](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/1402):

> I think the question is: what are you trying to do? Why is it relevant
>   to you whether a field is set or not and what do you intend to do with
>   this information?
>
> In proto3, field presence for scalar fields simply doesn't exist. Your
>   mental model for proto3 should be that it's a C++ or Go struct. For
>   integers and strings, there is no such thing as being set or not, it
>   always has a value. For submessages, it's a pointer to the submessage
>   instance which can be NULL, that's why you can test presence for it.

Comment: Just to clarify what you're saying: I know that optional is in proto2 and not in proto3, and singular is in proto3 and not in proto2. Are you saying that "singular string name" has no functional difference from "string name" in proto3? If so, why was "singular" added?

Comment: Yes it is the same, as `singular` is the default rule. The documentation should be updated, see issue [google/protobuf#3457](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/3457)

Comment: Cool.  This last comment (and the link) answers my question. Can you put that in your answer and I'll accept it. Thanks for the help!